# blocked package 5ghz wifi

Tags: wireless-networking, blocking, packet-loss

here my problem:
When I use my 5ghz wifi network, i get short(1-2 sec) blocked paquet. There's not loss but just blocked.
I'm using netgear R7000P router and NETGEAR A7000 WiFi USB3.0 adaptater .
with 2.4 ghz i never get this problem.

thanks for your help
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first screenshot shows consistent, frequent loss of signal. The picture below shows average latency of a third of a second and average jitter of half a second - those are *huge* numbers. As we're talking about averages, loss of signal accounts for that. This looks like interference, so my first step to improve this would be changing the Wi-Fi channel.

You don't specify your OS, so I'm guessing Windows. You can download a Wi-Fi analyzer like [inSSIDer](https://www.metageek.com/products/inssider/) and run it to see what other Wi-Fi devices are around you. Then you can set your router to broadcast in a channel with least amount of neighboring devices i.e. least amount of Wi-Fi interference. If your OS is different, you can search the internet to find an analyzer for your OS.

Your router should support wide channels, at least 40MHz, possibly 80MHz - applying that should also improve the performance. I don't know how Netgear calls wide channels, common terms are High Performance or High Throughput.

Consistent loss of signal like this is characteristic for certain types of non-Wi-Fi interference. That can originate from microwave ovens, alarm systems, automatic doors, certain lighting fixtures... and the source doesn't have to be inside your own space. inSSIDer and similar tools will not be able to detect this kind of interference, it requires a spectrum analyzer.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I swith on new channel and now it's working better.